# Comparison of Abraham and prophet from 1 Kings chapter 13

Tags: bible

In Genesis when Abraham was about to sacrifice Isaac on the altar he was stopped by an angel of God in Genesis 22:12. In this case Abraham somehow knew that the angel of God was sent by God and it was something that he should obey. He did not sin in this case since the word of God was obeyed.

In contrast, when reading 1 Kings 13 we see that the man of God had disobeyed God's command by eating with the older prophet even though God explicitly warned him not to eat or drink anything nor should he go back the path he went. In this case the man of God sinned because he was deceived. From Galatians 1:8-9, we know the correct thing to do is to not be tempted by the prophet.

If I were to be in Abraham's shoes knowing the bible verses I do, I would have thought to myself that not following through with the sacrifice would go against Galatians 1:8-9.

As I read through these verses, I ask myself if I were in similar situations as these people, how would I know what to do? How do we know when something is truly from the Lord or not?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.